# How does one "ride on the brake beam"?

Tags: etymology, railroads, great-depression

This would be a better fit for trains.stackexchange.com if it existed... but it doesn't, so I'm asking here. I started with the question of what it means when the narrator of *Eliza's Son* (1913) says his father ["paid for the brake to Skilby Castle"](https://archive.org/details/elizastories00pain/page/260/mode/1up). My best guess so far is that it meant a ticket for the [brake van](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brake_van#Passenger_brake_van), which I guess would have been less desirable than a proper passenger car? But anyway:

In researching that question, I kept coming across references to Depression-era hobos and such **"riding the brake beams"** ([Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=riding+the+brake+beams&year_start=1800&year_end=1990&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)), or sometimes "riding the brake blocks" or "riding the brake wheel." I don't know enough about how trains of the era (probably freight trains in this case) operated, to understand what this means. I'm hoping someone will explain, preferably with pictures or photographs.

An unusually almost-helpful description from [*The Diamond from the Sky*](https://archive.org/details/diamondfromskya01compgoog/page/n101) (Roy L. McCardell, 1916):

> With reckless haste he threw himself under a freight car and grasped and drew himself upon the brake beam. It was a strange way to travel for the erstwhile heir of Stanley. He had read of tramps **riding the brake beams,** but he had never thought he would come to do it; and now here he was in the dust and grime, on a creaking, narrow and greasy brake beam just over the cruel wheels that would mangle and grind him to death did he falter and fall.

A more typical throwaway reference from the [*Santa Ana Daily Register*](https://archive.org/details/santa-ana-daily-evening-register-1914-07-06/page/n5/mode/1up) (July 6, 1914, evening issue):

> He was not endowed with a long purse but by **riding the brake beams,** stowing away, working and begging he got to see every game.

Comment: Figure 1 of http://www.railway-technical.com/trains/rolling-stock-index-l/bogies.html shows the brake beam is part of the  "bogie", an assembly of 4 railway wheels on 2 axles, with lots of parts.  The  pictures on https://www.tedrail.com/products/classify/Brake%20Beam seem to show the same thing, but not the context of a brake beam in the bogie.  It looks like an uncomfortable place to sit!

Comment: There is a brake beam shown in the line drawing in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_railroad_truck_parts

Comment: Trains, [planes](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) and [automobiles](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) you're right! One is missing. I love all things trains and have a zillion questions. There is a mechanism to start a new site but it's not easy :-)

Comment: I suspect that the "brake to Skilby Castle" was probably [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brake_(carriage)) kind of brake.

Comment: @KateBunting thank you! It wouldn't surprise me if you're right about that. (I admit I started by picturing some sort of tramcar or cog railway and then got completely hung up on the "train ticket" angle without thinking about how silly it seems to take the railway to the seaside and then get on _another_ railway to "Skilby Castle." Its being a different form of transit would make a lot of sense, in hindsight.)

Comment: OK, I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 12):

[Horace Field Parshall; Henry Metcalf Hobart: Electric railway engineering, London 1907](https://archive.org/details/electricrailwaye01pars) has a large number of drawings of railway [bogies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogie), and one of them, Fig. 410 (after p. 440), gets the following description on [p. 446](https://archive.org/details/electricrailwaye01pars/page/446/mode/2up):

> The American type of brake foundation for steam railway passenger stock is well illustrated in the cast steel trailer bogie shown in Fig. 410. The brake blocks A are carried in steel castings B (brake heads), **each pair of brake heads being coupled by a brake beam C**, and suspended from the frame by the brake hangers D. Safety hangers E are also provided to support the brake beams in the event of a hanger breaking, and release springs F to hold the brake blocks off the wheels. In some instances the release spring also acts as a safety hanger. The angle of the brake beams can be adjusted by means of a turnbuckle G, so as to ensure the correct position of the brake blocks as they wear out. The pull rod H on the car body is attached to the upper end of the live lever I, which is at the outer end of the bogie, and is attached near its lower end to the brake beam. The lower end of this lever is connected to the lower end of the dead lever J by means of the brake rod K. The dead lever is attached near its lower end to the brake beam at the inner end of the bogie, and at its upper end to a fulcrum on the bogie frame, which is adjustable to take up the wear of the blocks. In the brake foundation of Fig. 410 a further adjustment can be made, the relative positions of J and K being adjusted by the set screw L.

[image]

The fact that the book is about electrical railways is not that important, but it should be noted that in the next paragraph the authors argue that this arangement is not suitable for bogies also carrying electrical motors, *"owing to the difficulty of finding room for the beams and the lower brake rod on account of the collecting gear and motors"*.

In this type of bogie the braking beam is mounted quite low, and as it

- is almost the lowest horizontal structure below the wagon
- is mounted on the outside of the wheel arangement
- is apparently made of wood and has a flat, if narrow, upper surface
- has a length of almost 6 foot

it seems to be usable as a place to lay down on.

[Another picture](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:406._District_Railway_Trailer_Truck.jpg), originally from the same book (Fig. 406 on p. 438), shows a photograph of the same arangement, with some minor differences.

Other bogies have the brake beam [hidden](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bogies,_Boston_Lodge_works,_Ffestiniog_Railway_-_geograph.org.uk_-_926598.jpg) between the wheel and the central beam, and carriages with only two fixed axles without a bogie, as used by a lot of lighter freight cars, might use slightly different [arrangements and materials](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Selbstentladewagen-Fccs-Axle.jpg). But at least all constructions with a [low beam mounted on the outside](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Buckeye_truck.jpg) would offer the same basic opportunity for a traveller.

Comment: Indeed. But not a nice place to ride.

Answer (score 12):

With reference to the original quotation from a 1913 novel - it's probably a reference to a type of carriage called a [brake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brake_(carriage)), that the characters could have hired to go on an excursion.